# establishing socket connection with two wifip2p device

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifip2p

I am imlementing wifip2p device discovery as service. I have successfully discovered a device and I have its WifiP2pDevice instance available. Now I want to establish a socket connection. For this first I have to connect to found device as

```
WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
config.deviceAddress = wifiP2pDevice.deviceAddress;
wifiP2pManager.connect(channel, config, listener);
```

Here I am successfully connecting to peer. But when I tried to connect socket for data transfer I found that I do not have proper `InetAddress` but I tried with following code

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.bind(null);
socket.connect( new InetSocketAddress(port), 1000);
```

As expected I got connection failed. So here most probably the problem is I don't have any hostname. I tried finding docs but could not found any thing.

In short I have a peer connected and have its wifip2pdevice instance, how will I establish socket connection?

Answer (score 0):

For transferring and receiving data between two devices through wifip2p.You need to create three threads.each  for client,server and clientServer thread for transferring data.refer the complete code.
 MainActivity.java file:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOnOff, btnDiscover, btnSend;
    ListView listView;
    TextView read_msg_box, connectionStatus;
    EditText writeMsg;

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    List<WifiP2pDevice> peers=new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    String[] deviceNameArray;
    WifiP2pDevice[] deviceArray;

    static final int MESSAGE_READ=1;

    ServerClass serverClass;
    ClientClass clientClass;
    SendReceive sendReceive;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialWork();
        exqListener();
    }

    Handler handler=new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuff= (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String tempMsg=new String(readBuff,0,msg.arg1);
                    read_msg_box.setText(tempMsg);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    private void exqListener() {
        btnOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
                {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    btnOnOff.setText("ON");
                }else {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    btnOnOff.setText("OFF");
                }
            }
        });

        btnDiscover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Started");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int i) {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Starting Failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                final WifiP2pDevice device=deviceArray[i];
                WifiP2pConfig config=new WifiP2pConfig();
                config.deviceAddress=device.deviceAddress;

                mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected to "+device.deviceName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String msg=writeMsg.getText().toString();
                sendReceive.write(msg.getBytes());
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialWork() {
        btnOnOff=(Button) findViewById(R.id.onOff);
        btnDiscover=(Button) findViewById(R.id.discover);
        btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.peerListView);
        read_msg_box=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.readMsg);
        connectionStatus=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
        writeMsg=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.writeMsg);

        wifiManager= (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        mManager= (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel=mManager.initialize(this,getMainLooper(),null);

        mReceiver=new WiFiDirectBroadCastReviever(mManager, mChannel,this);

        mIntentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    }

    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener=new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
            if(!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers))
            {
                peers.clear();
                peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

                deviceNameArray=new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                deviceArray=new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                int index=0;

                for(WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList())
                {
                    deviceNameArray[index]=device.deviceName;
                    deviceArray[index]=device;
                    index++;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,deviceNameArray);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            if(peers.size()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Device Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener connectionInfoListener=new WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo wifiP2pInfo) {
            final InetAddress groupOwnerAddress=wifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress;

            if(wifiP2pInfo.groupFormed && wifiP2pInfo.isGroupOwner)
            {
                connectionStatus.setText("Host");
                serverClass=new ServerClass();
                serverClass.start();
            }else if(wifiP2pInfo.groupFormed)
            {
                connectionStatus.setText("Client");
                clientClass=new ClientClass(groupOwnerAddress);
                clientClass.start();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    public class ServerClass extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket=new ServerSocket(8888);
                socket=serverSocket.accept();
                sendReceive=new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SendReceive extends Thread{
        private Socket socket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private OutputStream outputStream;

        public SendReceive(Socket skt)
        {
            socket=skt;

                try {
                    inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                    outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while (socket!=null)
            {
                try {
                    bytes=inputStream.read(buffer);
                    if(bytes>0)
                    {
                        handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ,bytes,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] bytes) {

                try {
                    outputStream.write(bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    }

    public class ClientClass extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        String hostAdd;

        public  ClientClass(InetAddress hostAddress)
        {
            hostAdd=hostAddress.getHostAddress();
            socket=new Socket();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAdd,8888),500);
                sendReceive=new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

WiFiDirectBroadCastReviever.java class:
public class WiFiDirectBroadCastReviever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public WiFiDirectBroadCastReviever(WifiP2pManager mManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel, MainActivity mActivity) {
        this.mManager = mManager;
        this.mChannel = mChannel;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action=intent.getAction();
        if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            // TODO: 19-Mar-19
            int state=intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,-1);
            if (state==WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED){
                Toast.makeText(context,"wifi is on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"wifi is off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            // TODO: 19-Mar-19
            if (mManager!=null){
                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel,mActivity.peerListListener);
            }
        }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            // TODO: 19-Mar-19
            if (mManager==null){
                return;
            }

            NetworkInfo networkInfo=intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if(networkInfo.isConnected()){
                mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel,mActivity.connectionInfoListener);
            }else {
                mActivity.connectionStatus.setText("device disconnected");
            }
        }else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            // TODO: 19-Mar-19
        }
    }
}
```